# On the complexification of real vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a real vector space. Theorem $2.11$ in [these](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) notes shows that the complexification is defined up to an isomorphism by the following characterization:

> A complexification of $V$ is a pair $(V',I)$, where $V'$ is a complex vector space and $I\colon V\to V'$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear function with the follwing universal property: For each $\mathbb{R}$-linear function $F\colon V\to W$ into a complex
> vector space $W$, there is exactly one $\mathbb{C}$-linear function
> $F'\colon V'\to W$ such that $F=F'\circ I$.

**Question:** Note that $I$ is injective$^1$, so that we can consider $V$ a subset of $V'$. That being said, I would like to show that
\begin{equation}
\forall v\in V:v=0\lor iv\in V'\setminus V
\end{equation}
and a hint would be appreciated.

---

$^1$ Proof: Suppose $v,w\in V$ and $Iv=Iw$. We want to show that $v=w$. To do so, consider some injective $\mathbb R$-linear function $F\colon V\to W$ into a complex vector space $W$ (of course, we need to show that such an $F$ exists to complete the proof, but this seems obvious to me). We have$$Fv=F'Iv=F'Iw=Fw$$ which implies $v=w$ since $F$ is injective.

Comment: read all about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings

Comment: In other words your definition is correct. What you defined is a special instance of what is called a *left adjoint functor*. The link mentioned gives a very general way to define some left adjoint functors between categories of vector spaces = modules over arbitrary rings. Indeed one can show that the replacement of $V$ with $V_{\Bbb C}$ is given by applying the tensor product $V_{\Bbb C} = V \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$.

Comment: Neither one is quite right. For the first, you need to exclude $v=0$. For the second, there are other things not in $V$. For example, if $V$ is one dimensional with basis $v$,  the the complexification has all vectors of the form $(a+bi)v$ with $a,b$ reals, the complement of $V$ is all things with $b\neq0$, and your map only hits the ones with $a=0$ (and you still have to be careful about the zero vector).

Comment: Your first claim holds: If $v \not= 0$ you can suppose there is some $w \in V$ such that $I(w) = i I(v)$. As $I(v)$ and $i I(v)$ are $\mathbb R$-linearly independent then so are $v$ and $w$ so we can find an element $\lambda$ of $V^*$ that sends $w$ to $0$ and $v$ to $1$. By assumption there is a unique linear functional $\lambda'$ of $V'$ that extends it. But that gives a contradiction as we get $0 = \lambda(w) = \lambda'(iI(v)) = i \lambda'(I(v)) = i \lambda(v) = i$. For the other you might want to try to show that $V' = I(V) \oplus iI(V)$.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Thank you for the comment. I guess it's better to ask a seperate question regarding the decomposition of the complexification as a direct sum. I have removed that part, so your comment fully answers my question and if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon In case you can have a look, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472747/572841) is my new question.