# Given a real vector space $V$, each element of the complexification has the form $v+iw$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Notation**: Let $W$ be some complex vector space, then $\widetilde W$ is the associated real vector space.

**Question**:
Let $V$ be a real vector space and $(V_\mathrm c,I)$ a complexification of $V$, i.e. $V_\mathrm c$ is a complex vector space and $I\in L(V,\widetilde{V_\mathrm c})$ such that for each complex vector space $W$ the function
\begin{align}
L(V_\mathrm c,W)&\to L(V,\widetilde{W})\\
A&\mapsto A\circ I
\end{align}
is bijective. I want to show that
\begin{align}
\Phi:V\times V&\to V_\mathrm c\\
(v,w)&\mapsto Iv+iIw
\end{align}
is bijective.

Comment: I don’t understand what you have to prove

Comment: are you sure? You wrote that you assume that the map is bijective

Comment: okay, I delete it

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally solved the problem (of course your feedback would be appreciated):

- Let $W$ be the complex vector space obtained by taking  the real vector space $V\oplus V$ and extending the scalar multiplication by$$i(v,w)=(-w,v).$$
- In addition, consider $J\in L(V,\widetilde W)$ defined by $Jv=(v,0)$. I claim that $(W,J)$ is another complexification of $V$.
- Clearly $I=\Phi\circ J$, i.e. $\Phi$ is the extension of $I$ w.r.t. $J$ and thus $\Phi\in L(W,V_\mathrm c)$ is the natural isomorphism from $(W,J)$ to $(V_\mathrm c,I)$.