# Complexification as a functor

Tags: category-theory

I know very little category theory, but I found some [good notes](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1612.09375) and I am confident that I can look up the definitions if something is unclear. That being said, [Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification#:%7E:text=In%20the%20language%20of%20category,(via%20the%20map%20f).) that complexification can be considered a functor, but doesn't elaborate and I don't know another reference. If someone can give a detailed explanation, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

For a field $k$ there is a category ${\rm Vec}_k$ whose objects are $k$-vector spaces and whose maps are $k$-linear maps. Complexification is a way to turn $\mathbb R$-vector spaces into $\mathbb C$-vector spaces. This suggests that there is a relation between the categories ${\rm Vec}_{\mathbb R}$ and ${\rm Vec}_{\mathbb C}$.

Let's try to define a functor $F : {\rm Vec}_{\mathbb R} \to {\rm Vec}_{\mathbb C}$ using complexification. On objects it works as expected: for $V \in {\rm Vec}_{\mathbb R}$ we define $F(V) = V^{\mathbb C} = V\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$. This is a complex vector space with $\mathbb C$-scalar multiplication given by
$$
 \lambda \cdot (v \otimes z) = v \otimes \lambda z.
$$

Now we need to define $F$ on the morphisms of ${\rm Vec}_{\mathbb R}$, a reasonable choice is to assign, for every $\mathbb R$-linear map $f : V \to W$ the map $F(f) = f \otimes_{\mathbb R} {\rm id}_{\mathbb C} : V^{\mathbb C} \to W^{\mathbb C}$. The map $F(f)$ is $\mathbb C$-linear.

You can easily check that $F$ satisfies the definition of a functor, for example if $f, g$ are composable $\mathbb R$-linear maps we have $$F(gf) = gf\otimes {\rm id}_{\mathbb C} = (g \otimes {\rm id}_{\mathbb C}) (f \otimes {\rm id}_{\mathbb C} ) = F(g)F(f)$$
and also $F({\rm id}_V) = {\rm id}_{F(V)}$.

If you want to read more about this kind of functors in general you should take a look at [induction and restriction of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings).

Comment: As far as I understand, you have shown that the construction of complexifications using tensor products defines a functor. I assume that a similar proof works for the construction through direct sums. Do you agree?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, you can define $G(V) = V \oplus V$ on objects and equip $G(V)$ with the complex scalar multiplication given by the matrix $J$ as the wiki page says. On morphisms it's a bit trickier than with the tensor product definition I guess. In the end you get a different functor $G$, but that should be isomorphic to the $F$ I described via the natural isomorphism $\alpha_V : V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong V \oplus V$ (a $\mathbb C$-linear isomorphism).

Comment: Well, for the tensor product you used the fact that there is an "obvious" "inclusion"$$V\to V\otimes\mathbb C$$and I think you can consider $$v\mapsto (v,0)$$to proceed analogously.

Comment: In fact, I am pretty sure that a complexification can be more generally defined as a pair $(W,I)$, where $W$ is a complex vector space and the "inclusion" $I\colon V\to W$ is a universal map, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472747/572841).

Comment: I'm not sure about the general definition, that may be an equivalent way to define things. 
Be careful though, the tensor product is not the same thing as a direct sum! And it happens that $v \otimes 0 = 0$. You may want to use $v \mapsto v \otimes 1$ for your inclusion $V \to V\otimes \mathbb C$.

Comment: When I wrote$$v\mapsto (v,0)$$I meant a function from $V$ to the direct sum. I believe we can consider this inclusion to show that the construction of complexifications through direct sums defines a functor completely analogous to your answer for the tensor product.

Comment: Regarding the "general definition", I believe that's precisely what you obtain if you unwrap the definitions of adjunctions. It seems very plausible to me, but since I am new to category theory you should be sceptical ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the obvious functor assigning a real vector space to each complex vector space, then complexification is an adjunction and this is just a reformulation of the definition I proposed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472747/572841) question (i.e. both characterizations are equivalent):

I had a look at the second chapter in Tom Leinster's [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) and it provides all the necessary results for a detailed explanation. In particular, we can prove the equivalence based on the different formulations of the definition of adjunctions that are presented in that chapter.